# Recommended Footprint width smaller than actual pad width

Tags: pcb, packages, footprint

I was just about to create a footprint for a Kingbright LED from the [KP-2012](http://www.sos.sk/a_info/resource/d/kingbright/KP-2012.pdf) series. From looking at the data sheet I am somewhat irritated:

[image: package]

[image: soldering pattern]

As you can see, the package pad with is 1.25mm, while the actual solder pattern width is only 1.1mm.

Why would this be desired?

Comment: "Recommended" - is recommended.

Answer (score 5):

It probably has to do with optimizing self-centering and prevention of '[tombstoning](http://www.ems007.com/articlefiles/69453-smt007_tombstone.jpg)'. The [HSMX-C670](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/hp/HSMG-C650.pdf) has a similar recommendation.

[image]